# Where is the .css reference in a WordPress theme?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, content-management-system, wordpress-theming

I am pretty new in WordPress and I have the following doubt about how link a CSS file into a WP theme.

For example this is the **header.php** file of the **TwentyTwelve** preinstalled template:

```
<?php
/**
 * The Header template for our theme
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="main">
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twelve
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="ie ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="ie ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<?php // Loads HTML5 JavaScript file to add support for HTML5 elements in older IE versions. ?>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
    <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
        <hgroup>
            <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
            <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
        </hgroup>

        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <h3 class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></h3>
            <a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'twentytwelve' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></a>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->

        <?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" class="header-image" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="" /></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </header><!-- #masthead -->

    <div id="main" class="wrapper">
```

This file start with the beginning  tag but I can't see the link to the used **style.css** file. Where is it?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Inside functions.php file of theme.function twentytwelve_scripts_styles()

Comment: mmm but where the twentytwelve_scripts_styles() method is called?!?!

Answer (score 5):

You should check `functions.php` file in your theme folder:

```
function twentytwelve_scripts_styles() {
 .....

 /*
  * Loads our main stylesheet.
  */
 wp_enqueue_style( 'twentytwelve-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

 ......
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentytwelve_scripts_styles' );
```

You can find more info about including styles and scripts in your wordpress site on this links:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: Ok but who call this twentytwelve_scripts_styles() method? In the header.php file is not called. I think that maybe in the header.php file call something that itself call twentytwelve_scripts_styles(=...or what?

Comment: It's called by the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action (as shown in the code in the answer by @andreivictor ).  The enqueued styles will be inserted when the `wp_head()` function is called.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to edit .css file, you can find it at wordpress theme folder.
this is default path:

wp-content\themes